# Create dropdown button to filter based on a categorical column

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['category'] = ['G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G1','G1', 'G1','G1', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2']
df['date'] = ['2012-04-01', '2012-04-05', '2012-04-09', '2012-04-11', '2012-04-16', '2012-04-23', '2012-04-30',
          '2012-04-01', '2012-04-05', '2012-04-09', '2012-04-11', '2012-04-16', '2012-04-23', '2012-04-30']
df['col1'] = [54, 34, 65, 67, 23, 34, 54, 23, 67, 24, 64, 24, 45, 89]
df['col2'] = round(df['col1'] * 0.85)
```

I want to create a plotly figure that has one x (`date`) and 2 ys (`col1` and `col2`). like this one, where the category dropdown button let's you select the category and updates the figure by filtering the `col1` and `col2` data for the selected category.

[image]

But I cannot make the dropdown to work and update the lines.

This is the code I tried:

```
# import plotly
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

x  = 'date'
y1 = 'col1'
y2 = 'col2'

trace1 = {
    'x': df[x],
    'y': df[y1],
    'type': 'scatter',
    'mode': 'lines',
    'name':'col 1',
    'marker': {'color': 'blue'}
}

trace2={
    'x': df[x],
    'y': df[y2],
    'type': 'scatter',
    'mode': 'lines',
    'name':'col 2',
    'marker': {'color': 'yellow'}
}

data = [trace1, trace2]

# Create layout for the plot
layout=dict(
    title='my plot',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Date', 
        type='date', 
        tickformat='%Y-%m-%d', 
        ticklen=5, 
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Old Standard TT, serif',
            size=20,
            color='black'
        )
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='values', 
        ticklen=5,
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Old Standard TT, serif',
            size=20,
            color='black'
            )
        )

    )

# create the empty dropdown menu
updatemenus = list([dict(buttons=list()), 
                    dict(direction='down',
                         showactive=True)])

total_codes = len(df.category.unique()) + 1

for s, categ in enumerate(df.category.unique()):
    visible_traces = [False] * total_codes
    visible_traces[s + 1] = True
    updatemenus[0]['buttons'].append(dict(args=[{'visible': visible_traces}],
                                          label='category',
                                          method='update'))


updatemenus[0]['buttons'].append(dict(args=[{'visible': [True] + [False] *  (total_codes - 1)}],
                                      label='category',
                                      method='update'))
layout['updatemenus'] = updatemenus

fig = dict(data = data, layout = layout)
iplot(fig)
```

I want make the category dropdown button with unique groups from `category` column, and selecting the `category` (either `G1` or `G2`) will filter that data and plot the `x` and `ys` for this selected category.

I already looked at dropdown page on plotly website but couldn't make the dropdown to work.

https://plot.ly/python/dropdowns/

Comment: Are you using plotly 3?

Comment: @vlizana yes, plotly version 3.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly 3 implemented `ipython widgets` native support, with this I'm not sure they are maintaining their old widgets. I suggest using `ipython widgets` because they are more standard and flexible, also I find them a bit easier to use even when it takes some time to get used to them. Here's a working example:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import ipywidgets as w
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['category'] = ['G1', 'G1', 'G1', 'G1','G1', 'G1','G1', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2', 'G2']
df['date'] = ['2012-04-01', '2012-04-05', '2012-04-09', '2012-04-11', '2012-04-16', '2012-04-23', '2012-04-30',
          '2012-04-01', '2012-04-05', '2012-04-09', '2012-04-11', '2012-04-16', '2012-04-23', '2012-04-30']
df['col1'] = [54, 34, 65, 67, 23, 34, 54, 23, 67, 24, 64, 24, 45, 89]
df['col2'] = round(df['col1'] * 0.85)

x  = 'date'
y1 = 'col1'
y2 = 'col2'

trace1 = {
    'x': df[x],
    'y': df[y1],
    'type': 'scatter',
    'mode': 'lines',
    'name':'col 1',
    'marker': {'color': 'blue'}
}

trace2={
    'x': df[x],
    'y': df[y2],
    'type': 'scatter',
    'mode': 'lines',
    'name':'col 2',
    'marker': {'color': 'yellow'}
}

data = [trace1, trace2]

# Create layout for the plot
layout=dict(
    title='my plot',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Date', 
        type='date', 
        tickformat='%Y-%m-%d', 
        ticklen=5, 
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Old Standard TT, serif',
            size=20,
            color='black'
        )
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='values', 
        ticklen=5,
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Old Standard TT, serif',
            size=20,
            color='black'
            )
        )

    )

# Here's the new part

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)

def update_fig(change):
    aux_df = df[df.category.isin(change['new'])]
    with fig.batch_update():
        for trace, column in zip(fig.data, [y1, y2]):
            trace.x = aux_df[x]
            trace.y = aux_df[column]

drop = w.Dropdown(options=[
    ('All', ['G1', 'G2']),
    ('G1', ['G1']),
    ('G2', ['G2']),
])
drop.observe(update_fig, names='value')

display(w.VBox([drop, fig]))
```

note that now you don't even need to import `offline` as the figure itself is an ipython widget. Plotly 3 also implemented an imperative way to write the code that I find to be really useful, you can read more about this and other plotly 3 features (that are sadly not really covered on the docs) in [this post](https://medium.com/@plotlygraphs/introducing-plotly-py-3-0-0-7bb1333f69c6).

**EDIT**

for more than one dropdown something like this should work

```
def update_fig1(change):
    aux_df = df[df.category == change['new']]
    aux_df = aux_df[aux_df.category1 == drop2.value]
    with fig.batch_update():
        for trace, column in zip(fig.data, [y1, y2]):
            trace.x = aux_df[x]
            trace.y = aux_df[column]

def update_fig2(change):
    aux_df = df[df.category1 == change['new']]
    aux_df = aux_df[aux_df.category == drop1.value]
    with fig.batch_update():
        for trace, column in zip(fig.data, [y1, y2]):
            trace.x = aux_df[x]
            trace.y = aux_df[column]

drop1 = w.Dropdown(options=df.category.unique())
drop2 = w.Dropdown(options=df.category1.unique())

drop1.observe(update_fig1, names='value')
drop2.observe(update_fig2, names='value')

display(w.VBox([w.HBox([drop1, drop2]), fig]))
```

Comment: thank you, worked perfectly. BTW, is there any workaround with the `Dropdown` options if I have more than 100 groups in the `category` column?

Comment: that version was to include an `All` option, but you can do `w.Dropdown(options=df.category.unique())` for example.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I had to replace `df[df.category.isin(change['new'])]` with `df[df.category == change['new']]` because it was throwing an error `TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(),`

Comment: BTW, is it possible to have a second dropdown button? let's say I have `category2` and want to filter by `category` and `category2`? Thank you :)

Comment: of course, the only thing is that you have to define another function to pass to the second dropdown. You can play with the widget layout like `display(w.VBox([w.HBox([drop, drop2]), fig]))` or so. There are also `Label` widgets that come in handy for annotating. More about widgets in the [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: I have created a second function and dropdown button as follow: `drop = w.Dropdown(options=df['category'].unique(), value = None)
drop.observe(update_fig, names='value')
drop2 = w.Dropdown(options=df['category1'].unique(), value = None)
drop2.observe(update_fig2, names='value')
display(w.VBox([w.HBox([drop, drop2]), fig]))` but the two buttons are not dependent, which is something I need.

Comment: You can access other dropdown current values using the `value` attribute, edited the answer with an example.