# How to save IPython Display

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am using this example to generate my plots
[Create dropdown button to filter based on a categorical column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671386/create-dropdown-button-to-filter-based-on-a-categorical-column)

How do I save this display to an HTML. I need to send the interactive graphs.

Edit:

This is what my code looks like:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import ipywidgets as w
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd


x  = 'date'
y1 = 'price'
y2 = 'SHB Car price'

trace1 = {
    'x':final_df2[x],
    'y': final_df2[y1],
    'type': 'scatter',
    'mode': 'lines',
    'name':'price',
    'marker': {'color': 'blue'}
}

trace2={
    'x': final_df2[x],
    'y': final_df2[y2],
    'type': 'scatter',
    'mode': 'lines',
    'name':'SHB Car price',
    'marker': {'color': 'yellow'}
}

data = [trace1, trace2]

# Create layout for the plot
layout=dict(
    title='Analysis',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Date', 
        type='date', 
        tickformat='%Y-%m-%d', 
        ticklen=5, 
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Old Standard TT, serif',
            size=20,
            color='black'
        )
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='price', 
        ticklen=5,
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Old Standard TT, serif',
            size=20,
            color='black'
            )
        )

    )

# Here's the new part

fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)

def update_fig(change):
    aux_df = final_df2[final_df2.brand.isin(change['new'])]
    with fig.batch_update():
        for trace, column in zip(fig.data, [y1, y2]):
            trace.x = aux_df[x]
            trace.y = aux_df[column]

drop = w.Dropdown(options=[
    ('All', ['bmw', 'ford','hyundai','mercedes-benz','nissan','opel','toyota','vw','audi', 'dacia', 'fiat', 'honda', 'kia', 'renault',
       'volvo']),
    ('bmw', ['bmw']),
    ('ford', ['ford']),
    ('hyundai', ['hyundai']),
    ('mercedes-benz', ['mercedes - benz']),
    ('nissan', ['nissan']),
    ('opel', ['opel']),
    ('toyota', ['toyota']),
    ('volkswagen', ['volkswagen']),
    ('audi', ['audi']),
    ('dacia', ['dacia']),
    ('fiat', ['fiat']),
    ('honda', ['honda']),
    ('kia', ['kia']),
    ('renault', ['renault']),
    ('volvo', ['volvo'])

])
drop.observe(update_fig, names='value')

display(w.VBox([drop, fig]))
```

And this is the dataframe that I am trying to display:
[image]

I am post 5 values here:

```
{'date': {0: Timestamp('2020-03-29 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-03-31 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-04-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-04-04 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-04-09 00:00:00')},
 'SHB Car price': {0: 137750.0,
  1: 62500.0,
  2: 32000.0,
  3: 43000.0,
  4: 66500.0},
 'brand': {0: 'volkswagen',
  1: 'citro�n',
  2: 'daewoo',
  3: 'citro�n',
  4: 'saab'},
 'str_id': {0: 'volkswagen_passat_2014_sedan_2012_2014_5_1598_105_front-wheel drive_semi-automatic_1.6 tdi bluemotion comfortline',
  1: 'citro�n_c5_2008_sedan____1560_110_front-wheel drive_manual_1.6 hdi sx',
  2: 'daewoo_nexia_2008_sedan____1450_63_front-wheel drive_manual_1.5 glx',
  3: 'citro�n_c5_2008_sedan____1560_110_front-wheel drive_manual_1.6 hdi sx',
  4: 'saab_9-3_2005_sedan____1900_138_front-wheel drive_automatic_1.9 tid vector'},
 'price': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'category': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}
```

This is what the graph looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my example below to generate the plotly scatter plot using plotly dropdown objects. `write.html` didn't work for you previously because it was part of IPython widgets, and not part of the plotly plot.

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

final_df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{'date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2020-03-29 00:00:00'),
  1: pd.Timestamp('2020-03-31 00:00:00'),
  2: pd.Timestamp('2020-04-03 00:00:00'),
  3: pd.Timestamp('2020-04-04 00:00:00'),
  4: pd.Timestamp('2020-04-09 00:00:00')},
 'SHB Car price': {0: 137750.0,
  1: 62500.0,
  2: 32000.0,
  3: 43000.0,
  4: 66500.0},
 'brand': {0: 'volkswagen',
  1: 'citro�n',
  2: 'daewoo',
  3: 'citro�n',
  4: 'saab'},
 'str_id': {0: 'volkswagen_passat_2014_sedan_2012_2014_5_1598_105_front-wheel drive_semi-automatic_1.6 tdi bluemotion comfortline',
  1: 'citro�n_c5_2008_sedan____1560_110_front-wheel drive_manual_1.6 hdi sx',
  2: 'daewoo_nexia_2008_sedan____1450_63_front-wheel drive_manual_1.5 glx',
  3: 'citro�n_c5_2008_sedan____1560_110_front-wheel drive_manual_1.6 hdi sx',
  4: 'saab_9-3_2005_sedan____1900_138_front-wheel drive_automatic_1.9 tid vector'},
 'price': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan},
 'category': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan}}
)

x  = 'date'
y1 = 'price'
y2 = 'SHB Car price'

fig = go.Figure()

brands = final_df2.brand.unique()
brands.sort()

for type in brands:
    df_temp = final_df2.query(f'brand== "{type}"')[y2]
    
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x = df_temp.index,
            y = df_temp.values,
            name = type
        )
    )

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(
        buttons=list(
            [dict(label = 'All',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [True, True, True, True]},
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'Citreon',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [True, False, False, False]}, # the index of True aligns with the indices of plot traces
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'Daewoo',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [False, True, False, False]},
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'Saab',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [False, False, True, False]},
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'Volkswagon',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [False, False, False, True]},
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
            ]),
        x=0.23,
        y=1.10
        )])


# Add annotation
fig.update_layout(
    annotations=[
        dict(text="Brand:", showarrow=False,
                             x=0, y=1.08, yref="paper", align="left")
    ]
)

fig.write_html('test.html')

fig.show()
```

It would be more complicated to plot the two series together on the same plot. I had decided to do separate series plots. You can generate the other series plots by changing y2 to y1 in the line `df_temp = final_df2.query(f'brand== "{type}"')[y2]`.

**References**

https://www.kaggle.com/jrmistry/plotly-how-to-change-plot-data-using-dropdowns

https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/

**Output**

[image]

Comment: It doesnt write drop down to html. It simply writes the current figure

Comment: @MubashirRaza If you don't mind, please share your code and output, I will see what I can help. Are you using Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Just added. Please check

Comment: Really need to save this one otherwise I'll have to make alot of effort to change it to completely plotly